# add array object into object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var objectz = {};
objectz.a = 1;
objectz.b = 2

objArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem'));

$.each(objArr, function(key,obj){
objectz.key = obj;
}

console.log(objectz);
```

I want to add array value into my existing obj, I got {1,2,10} where 3 to 9 is got override, where is my mistake?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` for the `$.each()` function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from syntax errors (copy/paste error?), your code is iterating through `objArr` and overwriting a property literally called `"key"` on `objectz` (i.e. `objectz.key`). You are not using the function parameter iterator called `key`. If you wanted to use the function parameter called key to update `objectz` then you probably want to use `objectz[key]`.

It is hard to guess what `localStorage.getItem('myItem')` returns. Assuming `objArr = [{c: 3},{d: 4},{e: 5},{f: 6},{g: 7},{h: 8},{i: 9},{j: 10}]`, here is a corrected version of your code:

http://jsbin.com/viwiko/edit?js,console

```
var objectz = {};
objectz.a = 1;
objectz.b = 2;

objArr = [{c: 3},{d: 4},{e: 5},{f: 6},{g: 7},{h: 8},{i: 9},{j: 10}];
//JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem'));

//$.each(objArr, function(key,obj){
//  objectz.key = obj;//overwrites a property called 'key' for each element of objArr
//});

$.each(objArr, function(key,obj){
  objectz[key] = obj;//key will be the zero based array index (i.e. 0 to 7 for the example data)
});

console.log(objectz);
```

Comment: I solved this too with objectz[key], so in this case I realized and know how to use obj[i] instead of obj.i, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
var objx = {};
objx.a = 1;
objx.b = 2

var objArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItem'));

$.each(objArr, function(key,obj){
objx[key] = obj;
}

console.log(objx);
```

object is a reserve word i believe if i am not mistaken

Comment: this doesn't work, anyway thx for reminding me bout the reserrved word

Comment: I think `Object` is reserved, but not `object` (lowercase 'O'). Although MDN [doesn't say either version is reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

Comment: Object is also not reserved, keywords are.